# How to remove duplicate pairs and sort according to the key?

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates

I have a list implemented for storing my integer values as pairs, initialized as follows

```
public static List<Entry<Integer,Integer>> bucketPairList= new ArrayList();
```

What I need to achieve is to remove all the duplicate integer pairs from the list (both keys and values might get duplicated. I need to remove similar pairs of them) and sort it according to the key.
Any suggestions how I could get it?

Comment: What is `Entry`? Is that the inner class of `Map`? If yes, that is not suitable for the situation you have dictated. You can rather create your own `Pair<K, V>` class.

Comment: yes that's the inner class of map

Comment: Do you consider (1,2) and (1,3) as duplication? Or just (1,2) to (1,2)?

Comment: no just (1,2) (1,2) would be duplicates not otherwise

Comment: I would use a `Set`, as @tintinmj suggested.  It will guarantee uniqueness on insert, since `Set`s can only have one of each object in it.

Comment: I'm not much familiar with sets so can you please explain how I could use them in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use Set to de-duplicate.

Have "Entry" Defined as (I renamed it to Data as it confuses with Map.Entry):

```
public class Data <T, U> {
    private T data1;
    private U data2;

    public Data(T d1, U d2) {
        this.data1 = d1;
        this.data2 = d2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if(!(object instanceof Data)) return false;
        Data<T, U> newData = (Data<T, U>) object;
        return data1.equals(newData.data1) && data2.equals(newData.data2);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = data1 != null ? data1.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (data2 != null ? data2.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return data1.toString() + " " + data2.toString();
    }
}
```

Then use HashSet, as this test shows:

```
public class DataTest {
    @Test
    public void runTest() {
        Set<Data<Integer, Integer>> set = new HashSet<Data<Integer, Integer>>();
        set.add(new Data<Integer, Integer>(1,2));
        set.add(new Data<Integer, Integer>(1,2));
        set.add(new Data<Integer, Integer>(1,3));
        set.add(new Data<Integer, Integer>(2,4));

        Assert.assertEquals(3, set.size());

        for(Data<Integer, Integer> data : set) {
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
1 3
1 2
2 4
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort :) but I still get duplicates. any ideas why would that be?